# How to link domain name and static ip linking together

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, web-deployment

I am new to all this. I have setup a Nginx server http://52.x.x.x I am testing it. I bought domain name from namecheap. I want domain name routed to the ip. What setting I should configure for this.

Comment: Create an A record on your DNS server that points to the IP address.

Comment: In the future, please read "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Comment: Mbaird I mean what setting exactly they are setting like a record dynamic DNS record and lots of which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure your instance is associated with an Elastic IP (EIP). If you do not do that, your instance's public IP address will change each time you reboot. Here are the instructions from AWS on how to setup and assign an EIP:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/GettingStartedGuide/getting-started-assign-eip.html

Note that if you don't associate that EIP to a *running* instance you will be charged. You can reference EIP pricing here:

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/

Next, as mbaird mentioned setup an A record in your DNS management at Namecheap.com. All you have to do is add an A record and enter the public EIP address that you received in the step above. As a start set your TTL (Time to Live) to 60 seconds. Here are the instructions on how to do that from Namecheap:

https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/434/78/how-do-i-set-up-host-records-for-a-domain

You can use www.whatsmydns.net to help troubleshoot any DNS propagation. (i.e. It takes a while for all of the world-wide root DNS servers to know that your domain name points to 54.x.x.x)

And finally - just as a suggestion - don't post your IP address in a forum like this unless you absolutely have to. Instead write something like, 54.x.x.x.

I hope this helps!